# marginLeft as a Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to animate a 'div' in the mobile version of my website.

```
$(function(){
    $( "#iconReorder" ).bind( "tap", tapHandler );

        function tapHandler( event ){
            $( "#iconReorder" ).animate({
                marginLeft: "15px"
                 }, 500 );
        }
});
```

When the 'div' wil change position I'd like to be able to tap once again on it and let it return to its default position.

I tried to create an 'if' statement...but I can't understand why it doesn't work.
I'd like assume the 'marginLeft' of my 'div' as a variable for my javascript code in order to move it to the right if 'marginLeft=10px' and move it to the left (default position) if the "new" 'marginLeft is not equal to 10px anymore.
I've tried with the following code:

```
var x = ("#iconReorder").style.marginLeft;      

    if (x = "10px") {
        $(function(){
            $( "#iconReorder" ).bind( "tap", tapHandler );

            function tapHandler( event ){
                $( "#iconReorder" ).animate({
                    marginLeft: "15px"
                }, 500 );
            }
        });
    } else {
        $(function(){
            $( "#iconReorder" ).bind( "tap", tapHandler );

            function tapHandler( event ){
                $( "#iconReorder" ).animate({
                    marginLeft: "10px"
                }, 1000 );
            }
        });
    }
```

Can somebody help me?
I hope that what I said is understandable.
Thank you

Comment: for starters, on line 3 you made an assigment (`x = "10px"`) instead of comparison (`x === "10px"`)

Comment: `("#iconReorder").style.marginLeft; ` => `document.querySelector("#iconReorder").style.marginLeft;`

Comment: then `bind` is deprecated method in jquery nowadays (won't affect your code now, but won't hurt to be up to date -- see the `on` method). And that if statement could just sit inside the `tapHandler` (along with `x` variable assigment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understood correctly, this should do:

```
var x = $("#iconReorder");      

x.on('tap', function () {
    var to = '10px', time = 1000;
    if (x.css('margin-left') === '10px') {
       to = '15px';
       time = 500;
    }
    x.animate({
        marginLeft: to
    }, time); 
});
```

or [in action](http://jsfiddle.net/TG8eT/). I replaced `tap` event with `click` so that I could see what I'm doing. Anyway it should work better now.

There might be some slimmer way to make it work, but I can't think of any at the moment (maybe some `toggle` method).

Comment: I've created a fiddle. This is an example.
I've tried with marginLeft because is the easiest solution I've found...
Basically, I'd like to move the box to the right at the first click and move it to the left at the second click.
Maybe you can find a better solution (instead of assuming marginLeft as a variable)
(http://jsfiddle.net/V6GBB/)

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the previous comment. Mmh no, the solution doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$( "#iconReorder" ).animate({
    'margin-left': 15
}, 500 );
```